# How to give the AuthUserFile access only for specific page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have one page on my root folder called `export.php`. Now I don't want to give access to this page to all the users.

What I am trying to achieve, If any user tries to access `export.php` page then one alert will display and it will ask for the username and password. Once login details are correct then the page will be accessible. I tried some code on htaccess.

Now I have two issues,

1) I am getting alert on all the pages. How do I set only for the export.php page?

2) After entering the username and password I am getting a server error.
[image]

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to the Hidden Files"
AuthUserFile 'http://localhost:8080/example/.htpassword'
Require valid-user
```

**Solution**.

First I found the path using 
`<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>`

Output: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/example/`

then I added path in htaccess file

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI /export SECURED

AuthName "Access to the Hidden Files"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/example/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: `AuthUserFile` should be a full filesystem path not a URL

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood this. i have to use system path?

Comment: It should be `AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpassword` and `.htpassword` should not have read/write permissions for group or others.

Comment: I am using MAC, So I have to use something like this nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/example/.htpassword   ?

Comment: @anubhava, Yes I think the path is correct I tried with a double-quote and It's working with a specific page. Can you help me with the second issue. After entering the correct details it's redirecting to a server error.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see exact reason of 500 error

Comment: @anubhava, Above path, is the local path, What path I have to use when it goes live on the server?

Comment: I found my issue. My path is wrong I have to use  /opt/lampp/htdocs/example/.htpasswd and issue got resolved.

Comment: Yes I always knew that's the reason and I mentioned this in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite all to router.php and then rewrite from php (small mvc for example https://github.com/breakermind/Tronix).

Better solution, check if the user has permissions in php file:

```
<?php
// User field from users table (add to session when logging)
if($_SESSION['user']['allow_export'] == 9 && isIpAddressAllowedFunc($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
    // show content
}else{
    // Redirect or log out user
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Is this answer for the second my issue?

Comment: This example shows how to get rid of the problem 